# SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 .dbml creation failed, but no error message

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

First, I type this at VS2010 Command Prompt

```
1:prompt x
2:xcd C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Test
3:xsqlmetal /dbml:TestMe.dbml /namespace:Test Database2.sdf
```

Result:

```
Error : Database can't be found.
```

Then I think, "OK, I'll write this instead at line 3"

```
3:xsqlmetal /dbml:TestMe.dbml /namespace:Test C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Test\Database2.sdf
```

Result:

It shows no error. But when I look at the C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Test, there is no .dbml file.

========================================================

What I've tried :
1. Retype the command.
2. Restart the computer, type it again.
3. Tried also:

```
3:xsqlmetal /dbml:TestMe.dbml C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Test\Database2.sdf

3:xsqlmetal /dbml:TestMe.dbml Database2.sdf
```

....but none works.

Other Information:

1. OS : Windows 7 32-bit
2. VS : VS2010 Professional SP1
3. DB : SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2
4. FW : .NET Framework 4.0 Runtime for 32-bit

Comment: and you are on the C: drive - try to add a command like "C:"

Comment: and where should I add the "C:" command? Sorry, but i really have no idea. Thanks.

Comment: okay i solved my problem. It should be : /dbml:C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Test\TestMe.dbml.

Thanks Erik, somehow you enlightening me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create SDF file to DBML Using Visual Studio 2010 than,
Write below line in visual studio 2010 command prompt than Enter and Execute it.

```
  SqlMetal.exe "EnterFilePath\CloudKase.sdf" /dbml:"EnterFilePath\CloudKase.dbml"
```

Also this SDF and DBML file in  used in Visual Studio 2012 Easy to Access and Implement the code.

Happy Coding :)